# Remove the left space from <ul> navigation

Tags: html, css, html-lists

The navigation appears with a margin to the left. I tried many things but I couldn't remove this left margin.

How can I remove that space?

Here is the [online demo](http://jsbin.com/jubadeze/1/edit).

```css
#navcontainer { padding: 0 5 20px 10px; }    
ul#navlist { font-family: sans-serif; margin-left: 0;}
ul#navlist li
{
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
  background-color: #EF634A;
}
ul#navlist > li
{
  height:38px; 
  line-height:38px;
}
ul#navlist li:hover
{
  color: #ffff00;
  background-color: #3E748A;
}
ul#navlist a
{
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height:1.1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

ul#navlist, ul#navlist ul, ul#navlist li
{
  padding: 0 8px;
  margin: 0 8px;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px #aaa;
}

ul#navlist li { float: left; 
}

ul#navlist li a
{
  color: #ffffff;

  //padding:10px;

  /*border: 1px #ffffff outset;
  height: 40px;*/ 
}


ul#navlist li:active
{
  color: #cccccc;
  background-color: #3E748A;
  border: 1px #ffffff inset;
  box-shadow: none;
}

ul#subnavlist { display: none; }
ul#subnavlist li { float: none;line-height:normal; }

ul#subnavlist li a
{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 14px;
}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist
{
  display: block;
  //display: inline-block;
  //display: table-cell;

  position: absolute;
  font-size: 8pt;
  padding-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: none;
}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a
{
  display: block;
  width : 360;
  height : 100;
  border: none;
  padding: 2px;
}

ul#navlist li:hover ul#subnavlist li a:before { content: " >> "; }

.left
{
  float:left;
  width:760px;
  background-color:#b0e0e6;
}
a.white:link {color: #fff;}
a.white:active {color: #fff;}
a.white:visited {color: #fff;}
a.white:hover {color: #fff;}
```

```html
<div id="navcontainer">
  <ul id="navlist">
    <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=1">PROGRAMME EUROPÉEN DE LUTTE <br>CONTRE LE TRUCAGE DE MATCHS</a></li>
    <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=2">ACTUALITÉS</a></li>
    <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=3">ANALYSE</a></li>

    <li id="active"><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4" id="current">THEMATIQUES</a> 
      <ul id="subnavlist">
        <li id="subactive"><a href="#" id="subcurrent">Lutte contre la corruption</a></li>
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=1">Evènements sportifs </a></li>
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=2">Bonne gouvernance du sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=3">Economie du sport</a></li>
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=4">Lutte contre le dopage</a></li>
        <li><a href="obs-geostrategique-sport.php?cat=4&id=5">Lutte pour l'intégrité dans le sport</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: which block are you reffering to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, web browsers apply a `margin: 8px` on `<body>` element by default, you need to remove that:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Also, they apply a `padding-left` property on HTML list elemets such as `<ul>` too, fix that by:

```css
ul#navlist {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;  /* <-- override the user agent stylesheet */
}
```

You're setting a margin and padding on the main `<ul>` element by:

```css
ul#navlist, ul#navlist ul, ul#navlist li {
  padding: 0 8px; /*   Here */
  margin: 0 8px;  /* & Here */
  list-style-type: none;
  box-shadow: 8px 8px 12px #aaa;
}
```

Remove `ul#navlist` selector from the group and set its style individually.

And finally, the first list item doesn't need to have a left margin:

```css
ul#navlist > li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Here is the **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/EvafEje/3/)**.